# Formal Sharpe Ratio Calculation

Tags: sharpe-ratio

Would appreciate clarity from senior quants on the correct way to calculate sharpe

Back in the zero interest rates days, I saw some senior quants would calculate sharpe ratio as avg(pnl)/std(pnl) and then annualize depending on strategy freq

1. Now that interest rates are > 5%, I'm very skeptical of this quick
   calc. If systems are too hardedcoded, would you just sythentically
   do ( avg(pnl) - (3m t-bill total pnl) )/ std(pnl)? Frankly I do not
   like this method, and I've seen people argue over whether it should
   be divided by std dev of excess returns over t bills
2. The other way I
   saw was calculating returns (%-wise) and doing the same for 3m
   t-bills, then doing excess return.
3. what if you are holding cash that
   you can't put into t-bills, (so you need to account for this drag)?
4. if your reporting period is 6 months to 1 year, would you roll the t
   bills or just take the 6m/1y bill as the risk free rate?
5. To account
   for increasing capacity and <3/4>, I start out with the fund's total
   cash, then do the daily value of the holdings + cash, take the avg
   of that pnl, minus the cash return from 3m to get the numerator. I
   take the avg of the time series above to get the denominator.
6. But  if the fund size changes do to inflows or outflows, how would you
   account for that? what about margin or funding considerations?

Comment: I get the impression you trade Futures (or in any case, derivatives) as opposed to Stocks and Bonds. Is that right? Who is the Sharpe ratio for, your own internal use or marketing/client reporting ?

Comment: correct I trade futures and options. we're privately held, so more internal use than client reporting

Comment: For Futures I think "avg(pnl)/std(pnl) and then annualize" still makes sense even with today's higher rates. Or at least I still use it.